# In which order are displayed Quote Line Items when SortOrder values are blank and order by SortOrder is selected?

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, quotelineitem, sortorder

In which order are displayed `Quote Line Items` when `SortOrder` values are blank and order by `SortOrder` is selected?

We try to sort `Quote line items` in our custom package the same way how they are ordered by Standard interface, but when `SortOrder` values are blank and order by `SortOrder` is selected, the records are returned in different order by SOQL query `ORDER BY SortOrder ASC` and on the standard user interface. Why such behavior is happening? How can we order the records in the same way they are ordered on the standard user interface?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like they are ordered by ID

[image]